# Grails 3 Controller Unit Testing: Domain class validation not working in a ControllerUnitTest

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.3

I'm upgrading an inherited Grails 2 app to 3.3.10. We have controller methods that rely on Domain class validation to control logic flow, but we can't get DomainClass validation to work in ControllerUnitTests when running in Grails 3

For example,
`Gift` and `RecipientAddress` are DomainClasses and `RecipientAddress.hasErrors()` is used to validate against the RecipientAddress constraints.

```
    def confirmAddress() {
        Gift gift = Gift.get(params.giftId)
        if (!gift) {
            render(view: "index", model: [invalid: true])
            return
        }

        recipientAddress = recipientAddressService.storeAddressInformation(params, gift)
        if (recipientAddress.hasErrors()) {
            render(view: "index", model: getAddressErrorModel(gift, recipientAddress))
            return;
        } else {
            return [
                    recipientAddress    : recipientAddress,
                    gift                : gift
            ]
        }
    }
```

In the following test, when I debug the controller method it does everything expected but `recipientAddress.hasErrors()` always returns `true` and the test fails.

ie:

```
@Transactional
class GiftDetailsControllerTest extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<GiftDetailsController> {

    @Shared
    @AutoCleanup
    SimpleMapDatastore dataStore = new SimpleMapDatastore([ConnectionSource.DEFAULT, "reporting"],
            RecipientAddress, Gift)

    def setup() {
        controller.recipientAddressService = Mock(RecipientAddressService)
    }

    void "test RecipientAddress Bad PhoneNumber"() {
        given:
        RecipientAddress recipientAddress = new RecipientAddress(
                phone: '123-456-789'
        )

        UnitTestDataFactory dataFactory = UnitTestDataFactory.getDataFactory()
        Gift gift = dataFactory.getMockGift()
        gift.save()

        params.giftId = gift.id

        when:
        recipientAddress.validate()
        controller.confirmAddress()

        then:
        recipientAddress.hasErrors()
        recipientAddress.getErrors().getFieldError('phone')
        1 * controller.recipientAddressService.storeAddressInformation(params, gift) >> recipientAddress
        view == '/giftDetails/index'
    }
}
```

Implementing `DataTest` ie: `...implements ControllerUnitTest<GiftDetailsController>, DataTest {` fixes the DomainClass validation, but breaks the controllers ability to get the saved Gift.

Is there a way get DomainClass validation working in a ControllerUnit test?

---

## Fix

Implemented DataTest with mockDomains and had to remove the custom dataStore.

```
@Transactional
class GiftDetailsControllerTest extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<GiftDetailsController>, DataTest {

//    @Shared
//    @AutoCleanup
//    SimpleMapDatastore dataStore = new SimpleMapDatastore([ConnectionSource.DEFAULT, "reporting"], RecipientAddress, Gift)

    void setupSpec() {
        mockDomains RecipientAddress, Gift
    }

....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way get DomainClass validation working in a ControllerUnit
>   test?

Yes.

You probably want something like this...

```
class GiftDetailsControllerTest extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<GiftDetailsController>, DataTest {

    Class[] getDomainClassesToMock() {
        [Gift]
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: OMG, thank you. I missed this in the docs. One more Q, do you know if we need to mock every property of the DomainClass? Based on the errors I'm now getting it seems like it, I'm getting errors on every missing property from Gorm props to 'date_created'

Comment: "do you know if we need to mock every property of the DomainClass" - No you don't.